# Recent changes to drop-down lists and display in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, mouse

I'm currently using Chrome version `32.0.1700` on Windows 7 and after last (or one of last) browser update I noticed some strange (at least to me) changes in look & feel of this browser. I would like to ask, if other also does suffer from these changes and if they're short-living bugs or permanent changes.

Changes that I found so far to drop-down lists and graphic rendering:

1. Removed support for clicking in drop-down lists -- you no longer can use left mouse click to scroll long drop-down lists, because there are no arrows on scrollbar and scrollbar itself doesn't react correctly on clicks (closes drop-down list instead of scrolling it). Using mouse wheel is currently the only way to get access to other (initially not visible) drop-down list's items.
2. When drop-down list has 4+ items, you're unable to hover (mark with blue background) last item on it. You can select it, but selection hovers stops on previous item -- this clearly look like a bug.
3. When you hibernate Windows with Google Chrome as active program (it's window maximized and covering all others), it is completely empty (not refreshed / redrawn) upon dehibernation. You must refresh current tab, by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or move mouse pointer around entire tab area.
4. At many points switching tabs causes that graphics elements comming from some non-standard UTF-8 fonts are incorrectly rendered as empty boxes. Fix is the same as above (refresh or move).

Plus stupidity (?) that I can use mouse clicks on scrollbars in normal lists, but can't in drop-down ones.

Has anyone else spotted these? Are these permanent changes or just bugs, that waits to be fixed.

Comment: 4 is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236298) that will be fixed in version 33.

Comment: update google chrome, it was a known bug.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately, point 4 is the smallest pain in my everyday usage of Chrome and I was hoping to get some explanations on points 1-3.

Comment: something like point 1 is driving me crazy, I cannot even open drop-down lists, so only keying through the items works, and on dynamic pages, this kills, as it reload on each key.